# colors.xml and multiple module

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, android-resources

I have 3 modules (common, app1, app2) in the common module I've a layout that I want to be black in app1 and white in app2.

**Layout.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@color/myColorBackground"
        android:weightSum="4">
...
```

**App1 colors.xml**

```xml
<ressources>
   <color name="myColorBackground">#fff</color>
</resources>
```

**App2 colors.xml**

```xml
<ressources>
   <color name="myColorBackground">#000</color>
</resources>
```

When I try to build the app I got a crash. Is there a solution to use colors like this ?

Comment: What's the reason of crash. Please add stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround by adding the `<color name="myColorBackground"/>` in my common module, now everything is working properly

Answer (score 0):

when using Modules you need the add the same file in every flavour Or use Common file in main module and override the specific file in required Module.[image: see the image and add files properly]